# Twitter API for login is not working in react-js application ( using react-twitter-login )

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter-login

Always getting [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gG2bx.png) error when I click on login button of twitter, also i added this call back URL in my developer-twitter account's project ( with localhost and local IP both ) , on click of twitter button box is opening but it show's blank screen inside, I am sharing my code block as well

[here is my twitter configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bohPo.png)

```
import TwitterLogin from "react-twitter-login";

export default (props) => {
  const authHandler = (err, data) => {
    console.log(err, data);
  };

  return (
    <TwitterLogin
      authCallback={authHandler}
      consumerKey={CONSUMER_KEY}
      consumerSecret={CONSUMER_SECRET}
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: The error is telling you what the problem is, your localhost server is not recognised by your Twitter app, so the request is blocked, Check [this](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-1-0a/authorizing-a-request) article to solve the problem

Comment: i have attached twitter config URL as well , it's same though i have configure twitter